# PartCover code details

Tags: code-coverage, partcover

I am using PartCover 2.2/2.3(trying with both) on win 7 x64. After generating report and selecting view coverage details, I can see for each method the code coverage. When I click on a method I see on the right list with block, block length, visit count and has source(set to yes).
I am using the money project from NUnit 2.5.2 samples.
However, it doesn't fill the code like shown here http://www.csharpcity.com/using-partcover-and-nunit-for-code-coverage/.
I haven't checked anything, everything is default.
Can you tell me how I can see the coverage code?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong assembly reference. Solved